# Template & memory-allocation

Tags: c++, templates, memory-management, new-operator

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T> T CreateArray(T a, int n)
{
    a = new T [n]; // mistake: double* = double**
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    double* a;
    int n = 5;
    a = CreateArray(a,n);
    return 0;
}
```

can I allocate memory using a template and new? And what my mistake?

Comment: Why do you want to create an array on your own, when std::vector will do that for you?

Comment: I want to create an array of n * n * n. And all of this as a special case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has some wrong things. First, you can do something like what you're trying to do, but you should write something like this:

```
template<class T> T* CreateArray(int n)
{
    T* a = new T [n];
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    double* a;
    int n = 5;
    a = CreateArray<double>(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you don't have to pass the `a` array (it will be copied inside `CreateArray`, and its changes won't be visible inside `main`). Note also that you define the template to returning a pointer `T*`, that is what `main()` `a` is expecting.

Comment: You missed the `CreateArray<double>(n)`.

Comment: Well, yes, fixed. I'm not sure if this will be needed in this case (the compiler can infer it), but I'll add it for completion.

Comment: @Diego: The compiler DO NOT use the return type for template argument deduction.

Comment: Why `a = CreateArray<double>(n);` better than `a = new double [n];`? It is useless. If you check the pointer (or do something more), I understand why a template function is used for allocate an array.

Comment: The problem is that I want a universal memory-allocation(double, int etc.)

Answer (score 3):

So others have explained why your code doesn’t work and how it can be improved.

Now I’ll show how you can *still* get the following code to compile – and to work properly:

```
 double* a = CreateArray(5);
 int* b = CreateArray(7);
```

The problem, as already mentioned, is that C++ does not infer template arguments from return types alone.

You can circumvent this limitation by making the above function return a simple proxy object. The proxy object has a single operation: an (implicit) conversion to `T*`. This is where the actual allocation happens.

The `CreateArray` function is therefore very simple (and *not* a template):

```
CreateArrayProxy CreateArray(std::size_t num_elements) {
    return CreateArrayProxy(num_elements);
}
```

As for the proxy:

```
struct CreateArrayProxy {
    std::size_t num_elements;

    CreateArrayProxy(std::size_t num_elements) : num_elements(num_elements) { }

    template <typename T>
    operator T*() const {
        return new T[num_elements];
    }
};
```

Easy as π.

Now, should you use this code? No, probably not. It offers no real advantage over direct allocation. But it’s a useful idiom to know.

Comment: ie better to dispense template when allocating memory?

Comment: @ObiSan Not in general but the above code can be unexpected. But apart from that you should generally **avoid** allocating memory altogether. The strength of C++ is that you *don’t* have to worry about memory management most of the time. For arrays, the solution is simple: always use `std::vector` instead of dynamic memory.

Answer (score 2):

You want to accept a **pointer** to the type you want to allocate:

```
template<class T> T* CreateArray(T* a, int n)
{
    a = new T [n];
    return a;
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: `template<class T> T* CreateArray(T* &a, int n)
{
    a = new T [n];
    return a;
}` - minor modification.

Comment: @Naszta: who said he wants to modify the argument?

Comment: ybungalobill. He or she is clearly trying to modify a, but as he or she noticed, it does not work inside the method, so it returned it and assigned directly in `main()` This is why using references to pointers would be maybe better for he or she to understand.

Comment: @Naszta: Write your own answer if you have a different one. FYI, I think it's wrong.

Comment: @Diego: Nah, changing a variable passed in by reference _and_ returning it it just confusing. There is in fact _nothing wrong_ with returning a new value.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to keep empty pointers value NULL.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T> bool CreateArray(T * &a, int n)
{
    if ( a != 0 )
      return false;
    a = new T [n];
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    double* a = 0;
    int n = 5;
    CreateArray(a,n);
    return 0;
}
```

`vector` could be a good solution, too. I think it is better one, because you won't make memory leak(s).

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> a;
    int n = 5;
    a.resize(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may prefer that, but it's now an entirely different program with different semantics.

Comment: Interesting solution, but the compiler does the expression "T* &" and perceives as the multiplication of variables, doesn't?

Comment: @ObiSan: MS compiler just accepted it. It is a reference of a pointer.